what are the scriptural sources for how deities are represented in sculpture,paintings etc.?
images of Vishnu, Rama, Krishna et al seem to invariably show them in traditional Indian garb - like in the Raja Ravi Verma paintings.
there don't seem to be images of Siva wearing a Dhoti.
Are present-day depictions of deities based on scripture?

These come from dhyaan mantra across various texts, each scriptures talk of it. Same deity may have multiple dhyaan mantras. And how to sculpt them or portray them in physical world is dealt in Shilpa shastra. For example, Ganapati follows measurement of 5, when sculpting his Vigraha or painting. Present day depictions are more of artistic endeavour than Shastric, tho many art pages offer Shastric images and Vigrahas too.

Most prominent is the Vishnudharmottara Purana. Then comes the Matsya Purana & Agni Purana. Modern day depictions are mostly based on the ancient depictions based on these texts & dhayanamantras in other texts. Agamic literature is full of such dhyanamantras & thus a good source of art. There are also shilpasastra texts like Aparajitapriccha & Rupamandana (composed by architect Mandan a under the patronage of Rana Kumbha). However, regional variations exist. In North, 'shyama' complexion is represented with blue colour, but in South, green is uses.

Same question --- https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/27517/4732
