# how to realize that a person got mantra siddhi

Tags: mantras, siddhi

What are the symptoms,how we will come to know that, a person got mantra siddhi , after a "N" number of jaap of a particular mantra?

Say, if it is shakteya tradition , then about bala parameswari or Kaali moolamantra, if a person completed many lakhs/(Crores?) of HER moolamantra, will that person get mantrasiddhi?

how come he- sadhak, upasaka - will come to know, realize that, he got a siddhi.

Or in shaivism, can I do jaap of om nama:ssivayaa --- whenever I get time (while travelling, inside office, when we speak to others etc ) -- and after many months/ years of continuous jaap, will I get siddhi?

Comment: You can chk my answer here: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/26566/what-are-signs-of-mantra-siddhi

Comment: Another thing is for mantra siddhi one needs to do purascharana .. and while doing it  one needs to be following certain strict rules .. like sleeping on the floor, celibacy, restricted food habbit etc .. and purascharana shd not be done while walking, on the move, etc .. it has to be done while seated and the count shd also be kept