# How to meet lord Ram in real-life?

Tags: rama, hanuman, kali, nama-japa

I'm a Ram Bhakta. I was told to chant Hanuman Chalisa when I was 16 years old by a relative. I was an eccentric person with a lot of temper and bad mood swings. After starting Hanuman Chalisa chant daily I found myself at peace and I had phenomenal growth in my life (both academically and personally). Slowly I started liking lord Ram and I'm always chanting his name for everything. There was a subtle transition from Swami Hanuma to Lord Ram(Of course a lot happened in between). I'm at a stage where I want to meet him. I'm doing Ram naam japa but I'm not able to concentrate well. Also sometimes I often see Maa Kali in my thoughts. What's the meaning of all this? I'd appreciate your replies....

Comment: Read abt the life of Swami Samarth Ramdas of Maharashtra.He did one maha-purushcharana of the Taraka Ram Mantra-Shri Ram Jai Ram Jai Jai Ram 13 crore times with extremely strict rules and in the end received the direct  divine darshana of Lord Shri Ramachandra! See [this](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/51716/can-we-have-a-vision-of-any-god-with-13-crore-nama-japa) post for more info. Hope this helps!

Comment: That being said it dosen't guarantee a darshana, but you will receive a tremendously powerful experience at the end if done properly!

Comment: Welcome to Hinduism StackExchange!! While HSE do share great information on Hinduism, however, it does not offer personalized advice answers. Please take a [tour](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/tour) of the site before getting started.